# jQuery :nth-child() selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Hi please look at the HTML below. I am trying to use jQuery to get every 3rd instance on the DIVs with `class="box"` contained within the DIV with `class="entry"` to have a no right hand margin:

My HTML code:

```
<div class="entry">

    <div class="box">
        SOME HTML....
    </div><!-- end .box -->

    <div class="box">
        SOME HTML....
    </div><!-- end .box -->

    <div class="box">
        SOME HTML....
    </div><!-- end .box I Want to remove right hand margin on this div -->

    <div class="box">
        SOME HTML....
    </div><!-- end .box -->

    <div class="box">
        SOME HTML....
    </div><!-- end .box -->

    <div class="box">
        SOME HTML....
    </div><!-- end .box I Want to remove right hand margin on this div -->

    <div class="box">
        SOME HTML....
    </div><!-- end .box -->

    <div class="box">
        SOME HTML....
    </div><!-- end .box -->

    <div class="box">
        SOME HTML....
    </div><!-- end .box I Want to remove right hand margin on this div -->

    </div>
    <!--end entry-->
```

My attempt with jQuery:

```
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("div.entry:nth-child(3)").css("margin", "0px");
        });
   </script>
```

I can't get this working can anyone please help? Thanks in advance!

---

thanks to all who helped the solution provided is indeed correct. I am coding up a supplied template and found that JQuery had been set to run in compatibility mode hence $ was the problem.

Comment: I had the same problem too.
I created a container div, ".entry" in this case, and used the selector 'div.entry>div.box:nth-child(3)'which worked greate.
thanks for help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the docs (my emphasis)

> Matches all elements *that are the nth-child of their parent* or that are the parent's even or odd children.

You're currently selecting the parent, while you should be selecting children:

```
$("div.entry > div:nth-child(3)").css("margin", "0px");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help much appreciated unfortunately that did not work.

Answer (score 7):

nth-child also seems to be non-0 indexed. Keep that in mind if you're used to indexing at 0.

Comment: Thats reallyn useful...thnx!

Answer (score 3):

Your [`:nth-child`](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/nthChild) selector does not reference `n`, and you need to reference the inner `div` in your selector.

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div.entry div:nth-child(3n)").css("margin", "0px");
});
```

Comment: Sorry - just spotted that your selector was wrong too. You still need the `3n` rather than just `3`, but you also need to put ` div` before the `nth-child` stuff. I've tested this and it works.

Comment: I still can't get this working using the solution you provided. I have the div.entry nested inside a couple of other div's could this be the reason why? Do I have to reference the entire path i.e "div1 > div2 > div.entry div:nthchild(3n)"?

Comment: Whether it's nested insid eother divs should make no difference, you certainly don't have to reference the entire path. Is there anything else interfering with those innermost divs? Are there any other divs inside entry that you don't want to be affected? Perhaps you want `$("div.entry div.box:nth-child(3n)").css("margin", "0px");`

Comment: FWIW, I've tested my solution with the `entry` div nested inside other and it works fine.

Comment: @Dominic: Thanks again for the help. I've just tried running this simple line $("div.entry").addClass("test"); and thats not working I must have something conflicting but I've no idea what as I have stripped out all other JQuery (apart from the library itself).

Answer (score 1):

Try this selector:

```
div.entry > div.box:nth-child(3n)
```