# jQuery create an array of objects with a specific class

Tags: jquery, class, arrays

Is there an array created somewhere of all the objects with a specific class?  I want to find the sixth div with class="clCategory".  Is there something like:

```
$('.clCategory:sixth').css(...);
```

or

```
$('.clCategory')[6].css(...);
```

Or do I have to create the array at the same time I programmatically create each of the DIVs with class="clCategory"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`eq(x)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

It's 0-based, so the 6th would actually be #5

E.g.:

```
$('.clCategory:eq(5)')
```

You can also query for `$('.clCategory')` and access it at `[5]` or even `.get(5)`. The difference with either is that you would be getting the DOM HTMLElement, not the jQuery wrapped element as in my previous example.

Comment: Matt, thanks for the answer.  I know this is a little off topic to the comment, but what is the difference between DOM HTML Element and jQuery wrapped element?

Answer (score -1):

You have to use nth child selector. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026885/jquery-nth-child-selector) related post.

Comment: .eq() in jquery is meant for this. not the nth selector