# Paint with a color specific li elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this html structure:

```
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
...
</ul>
```

I need to paint red the li elements with the following sequence.

1st,3rd,7th,11th etc

Have in mind that the li elements are dynamically produced.

Comment: sorry, what is the exact sequence rule? you need to colour the first element and then every `4n-1` element? the **etc** part is not clear... could you update your question, please?

Comment: 1, 3, 7, 11 isn't a mathematical sequence. Are you sure you have those numbers correct?

Comment: What does the sequence represent, it's not making any sense to me :7

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery :nth-child() selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026885/jquery-nth-child-selector)

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about the sequence that you're trying to produce? You skipped five.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure this will do.

```
<script>$("ul li:first, ul li:nth-child(4n-1)").css({'color':'red'});</script>
```

Using jQuery you don't have to worry about IE, it will work crossbrowser.

Comment: This won't work if any elements are added to the list after you run this code. _Have in mind that the li elements are dynamically produced._

Comment: Can I ask to the @paokg4 why this answer was accepted when it was wrong formulated (something like `$('li:eq(2)')`) and when there was a couple of right answers (mine and @musefan) previously written? Thank you.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan. Thank you for your answer. This answer was accepted because I pasted only this line 
<script>$("ul li:first, ul li:nth-child(4n-1)").css({'color':'red'});</script>
 and it worked properly and its cross browser.

Comment: @Esailija, Its obvious that my code works. It depends when you will execute the code. You can execute it after an ajax call, or on document ready. Also its cross browser.

Comment: @paokg4 I just noticed that when you accepted this answer, the answer was completely wrong.

Comment: I thought it was an example.
Yes, you talk about (2n)..., I'd just replaced 2n with the 4n-1.

Answer (score 5):

*Waiting further information*, if you need to paint the first element and then every `4n-1`th element, just use psuedoclasses:

```
li:first, li:nth-child(4n-1) { 
   color: ... 
}
```

as aside note, these psuedoclasses don't work on older IE browser, so if you need to also style some specific list-items for IE7, consider to output some classes while you're generating markup on server-side (or apply style to the elements via jQuery)

Answer (score 3):

This should work for selecting odd elements

```
$("li:odd").css("color", "#F00");
```

[See here for more info on the JQuery odd selector](http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/)

[You can view a working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/uT3qt/)

---

As I seem to have misread your initial sequence...

there are other JQuery selectors you can [check out here](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) that help with sequence matching.

Some example code that matches your sequence could be...

```
$("li:first").css("color", "#F00");
$("li:nth-child(4n-1)").css("color", "#F00");​
```

[See here for example](http://jsfiddle.net/aGpmJ/)

Comment: @ZoltanToth: Yes, I seem to have misread that part. Maybe on OP typo, lets wait and see

Comment: sure :) his sequence is strange

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS child selector.

Put a style li:nth-child(odd) { color: red; } on the UL tag.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo

Answer (score 0):

Use this
      `$("li:odd").css("color", "red");`

Answer (score 0):

You could add a HTML class to differentiate between even and odd items when generating the list. Then it will be easy to apply different CSS rules to the elements, according to their ordinal position.

I'm gonna write a very generic PHP code to do it, assuming you generate the list from an array called $list:

```
<ul>
<?php
for( $j=1; $j <= count( $list ); $j++ ):

    if( ( $j % 2 ) == 0 )
    {
        $class = 'even'
    }
    else
    {
        $class = 'odd'
    }
?>
    <li class="<?php echo $class;?>"><?php echo $list[$j-1];?></li>
<?php endfor;?>
</ul>
```

I just saw you tagged the question with jquery and javascript, you should check the jQuery documentation first, and as a general rule, GOOGLE IT before you ask for help.

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

I'd still do it using the server-side language that generates the list.